# Vue3 ref not updating when the array is changed

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

This issue occurs only when I'm trying to update an array which uses Vue's "ref".

Here's some basic example code of what I have:

```
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue';

let arr = ref([]);

function someUpdateFunc(val) {
    arr.value.push(val);

    console.log(arr.value);
}
</script>
```

If I check the console in my browser I see the updated array as expected. However, when I try to run some functionality in the same component that needs the updated values it doesn't work.

To confirm this I installed the Vue dev tools Chrome extension and checked the array on the component. It matches the functionality not working as the variable never updates and looks like this:

```
arr: Array[0] (Ref)
```

Please can anyone advise why my array isn't updating?

Thanks,

Comment: `when I try to run some functionality` - perhaps that's the code that is *doing it wrong™* because the code you've shown looks OK - can you change to `const arr = ref([]);` that way, code you haven't shown can't accidentally break the ref

Answer (score -1):

try use this.$set?

this.$set("Object"，"Properties of Object"，"changeValue")

Comment: `$set` only exists in Vue 2. The question's title indicates Vue 3.

Comment: you are right ,its my fault,thanks